# JAVA BST return node instance of BST node?

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I'm doing a BST project which is search a value in the BST and return if it was found. I used a test method to check the codes, and it work fine. Problem came from the return type I guessed.

```
public BSTNode contains(BSTNode root, String needle) {
     BSTNode current = root;
     while (current != null) {
         if (current.getData().compareTo(needle) > 0)
            current=current.getLeft();
        else if (current.getData().compareTo(needle) < 0)
            current=current.getRight();
        else if (current.getData().compareTo(needle) == 0)
            return current;
        else current=null;
    }
    return current;
}
```

result:

```
BSTNode node = bst.contains(root, "delta");
    Assertions.assertTrue(node instanceof BSTNode);
```

false;

```
BSTNode node = bst.contains(root, "delta");
    Assertions.assertTrue(true);
```

true;

As my understanding, I believe the codes work fine and the value return was right. I just don't understand the "node instance of BSTNode" why it was false and how can I fix it?

Thank you in advanced

[image]

Comment: I flip the wrong side on the comparison! I edited it already so ppl can find their answer if they have the same problem. Thanks @Louis Wasserman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method, as written, can only ever return null.  You only exit the `while` loop when `current` is `null`, and then you return `current`.  `null instanceof Anything` is always false.

The line `current=current;` will also cause an infinite loop if the value is found.

Both of these can be addressed at once: you should return `current` when the comparison is 0.

Comment: Thank you for the explaination. I try to change it to  else if (current.getData().compareTo(needle) == 0)
            return current; But it still got false

Comment: Well, have you built the BST correctly?  Print out the actual node, not just whether it's a BSTNode.

Comment: Then null was returned and "delta" was not in the tree.

Comment: when I debugged the codes, I can see the BST and delta is inside the tree.

Comment: as @LouisWasserman said it return null because current have to be null so it can exit the while loop.

Comment: You have also flipped left and right.  (Your comparisons are in a weird order.)

Comment: @Louis Wasserman Thank you! that was a stupid mistake. This is my first time trying BST it really complex to me! turn out I really flip the comparison!

Answer (score 0):

As you already got the point where you were actually wrong, I am adding one more constraint, by modifying your existing code.

In case of BST, there would be 3 points:

1. current node is equal to key node
2. current node is greater than the key node
3. current node is lesser than the key node

Therefore you need iterate until unless you found the key you were looking for or you traversed all possible keys. In either case you need to stop your iteration.

```
   public BSTNode contains(BSTNode root, String needle) {
     BSTNode current = root;
    /* the variable you will return at the end */

     BSTNode result = null;
    /* iterate the loop until current becomes null or result becomes not null */

     while (current != null && result == null) {
         /* when you found what you were looking for */
         if (current.getData().compareTo(needle) == 0){
            result = current;
         }else if (current.getData().compareTo(needle) > 0){
            current=current.getLeft();
         }else{
            current=current.getRight();
         }
    }       
    /* return the result at the end, it will be either null or the value you were looking */
    return result;

   }
```